# IP redirect IPv6 HTTP:X-FORWARDED-FOR

Tags: apache, .htaccess, ipv6

I cant seem to get a straight answer anywhere. 
Would this line work to IP lock a page?

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-FORWARDED-FOR} !(89.101.70.19 | 2a02:8084:6aa0:6980:2ce9:7fcd:a298:2313)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to lock a website to a specific IP use the following in your .htaccess:

```
Order Deny,Allow
Deny from all
Allow from 89.101.70.19
Allow from 2a02:8084:6aa0:6980:2ce9:7fcd:a298:2313
```

Comment: Thanks for your input @Sander Steffann completely missed that part!

Comment: So just to be clear for IPv6 there is nothing special that need to be added for it to work?

Comment: Thanks, No idea how long I have been looking for that answer

Answer (score -1):

You could try this:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-FORWARDED-FOR} !(89\.101\.70\.19|123\.123\.123\.123)
```